# Unresolved reference : retrofit while creating retrofit instance

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

I am working on an android app which request Mars photos ans use it to display it on screen.
To make an request.And trying to use A public Api object that exposes the lazy-initialized Retrofit service.
below is source code with error

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

class MarsApiService {
    public val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(Companion.BASE_URL)
    .build()
interface MarsApiService{
    @GET("photos")
    fun getPhotos(): String
}
object MarsApi {
    val retrofitService: MarsApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(MarsApiService::class.java) }
}



companion object {
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com"
}
}
```

17th line the code inside object MarsApi pops up errors Unresolved reference : retrofit. The call to create() function on a Retrofit object is expensive and the app needs only one instance of Retrofit API service. So, i exposed the service to the rest of the app using object declaration.

**What I have tried:**

The code is working if i bring code inside object MarsApi out but doing so may result in multiple instance of retrofit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### code1

```kotlin
interface MarsApiService {
    @GET("photos")
   suspend fun getPhotos(): String

    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com"
        val marsApiService: MarsApiService by lazy {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build().create(MarsApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

#### code2

```kotlin
private const val BASE_URL = "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/"

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface MarsApiService {

    @GET("photos")
    suspend fun getPhotos(): String
}

object MarsApi {
    val marsApiService: MarsApiService by lazy { retrofit.create(MarsApiService::class.java) }
}
```

#### run

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val rs = marsApiService.getPhotos()
    println(rs)
}
```

In your code, `retrofit` by lazy reference not resolved cause of `retrofit` is `property` of `class`, move the `retrofit` globally  like using `(Companion) object` or   like *code2* (highest hierarchy?)

Comment: [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-getting-data-internet?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-4-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-getting-data-internet#5)

Comment: check the above link its a official tutorial about how to use retrofit. What's going wrong in this.

Comment: Hey thank you I was writing whole code inside a class your Code 2 helped me figure out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#accessing-variables-from-anonymous-objects)

make you clear the difference between object and companion object and when to use them. Happy learning

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It was the same problem that I had.
I solved it just excluding the class `MarsApiService`
I didn´t use `companion object` too.

The **right code** is below

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.GET

private const val BASE_URL = "https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com"

public val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .baseUrl(Companion.BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface MarsApiService{
    @GET("photos")
    fun getPhotos(): String
}

object MarsApi {
    val retrofitService: MarsApiService by lazy { 
        retrofit.create(MarsApiService::class.java) 
    }
}
```